# elements were not added an array on a react state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I tried this Correct modification of state arrays in React.js

[Correct modification of state arrays in React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26253351/correct-modification-of-state-arrays-in-react-js)

any elements have not added to the array.

[...array,[{},{}]]
and

this.state.aaaa.concat[newArray] are invalid for my code.
I would like to set a JSON-array to a state but it does not work.

```
const setCountries = COUNTRIES.map((country) => {
    console.log("OMG!");
    return {
      id: country,
      text: country,
    };
  });


class Stack extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      testarray: [],
    };

    this.setState( {testarray: setCountries});
    console.log("MO"+JSON.stringify(setCountries))
    console.log("UU"+JSON.stringify(this.state.testarray))
```

Console says. MO

```
MO[{"id":"Afghanistan","text":"Afghanistan"},{"id":"Albania","text":"Albania"},{"id":"Algeria","text":"Algeria"},{"id":"Andorra","text":"Andorra"},{"id":"Angola","text":"Angola"},{"id":"Anguilla","text":"Anguilla"},{"id":"Antigua & Barbuda","text":"Antigua & Barbuda"},{"id":"Argentina","text":"Argentina"},{"id":"Armenia","text":"Armenia"},{"id":"Aruba","text":"Aruba"},{"id":"Australia","text":"Australia"},{"id":"Austria","text":"Austria"},{"id":"Azerbaijan","text":"Azerbaijan"},{"id":"Bahamas","text":"Bahamas"},{"id":"Bahrain","text":"Bahrain"},
```

UU[]

The other way

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {

      suggestions: [{ id: "Thailand", text: "Thailand" }],
    };
    this.setState( {suggestions:  [{ id: "India", text: "India" }]  } );
```

```
 this.setState( {suggestions:  [...this.state.suggestions,[{ id: "India", text: "India" }]]  } );
```

was also invalid.

The result is UU[{"id":"Thailand","text":"Thailand"}]... India was not set.

Answer (score 0):

For both variable as array so you need spread both inside the array

like

```
[...prev,...new]
```

Your case better use setState callback

```
this.setState(state => {
  state.suggestions = [...state.suggestions, ...[{
    id: "India",
    text: "India"
  }]]
  return state
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are logging just below the setting state, which is async actually..

please try this

```
this.setState( {testarray: setCountries},()=>{
       console.log(this.state.testarray)
});
```